# What do call individuals who express their opinions as if they were facts?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, pejorative-language, popular-refrains

We all know some individuals who don’t express their opinions as:

> I *think* this is going to happen...

Instead, they express it as if it were fact or news, e.g.:

> Next month the price of (something) *is going to* increase by 10 percent.

What do you call such people? And are there any idioms or sayings to describe them?

Comment: If they turn out to be right, you call them _prescient_. But I don't think this is what you're looking for. I can't think of a word for them.

Comment: They're _self-styled experts_.

Comment: "Windbag" is good... "Pompous ass" fits in some situations... "Pathological liar"? My friends just call me "arrogant".

Comment: It is, of course, not unusual for an individual to make a "prognostication" that, say, the economy will tank in September (you heard it here first!), but a lot depends on context.  Predicting that the economy will do this or that, or that gas prices will go up or down, is ordinary "chit-chat", especially when folks (mainly guys) are sitting around "swapping lies".  But to claim that next month the (US) government is going to start collecting everyone's guns is pure paranoia.

Comment: *Blowhards* often do this.

Comment: *Politicians*, of course

Comment: Every single person.

Answer (score 7):

Your question title doesn't match the question body, in my opinion.

A word for someone who regularly expresses opinions as facts is [***pontificator***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pontificate):

> [One who] expresses opinions or judgements in a dogmatic way.

An example would be a programmer who insists that XML is the solution to everything.

However, your example involves a prediction. It is generally understood that predictions are inherently unreliable. Yet, there seems to be a demand for such predictions anyway. Broadcast media satisfy that demand by hiring [***pundits***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pundit):

> A source of opinion; a critic

Comment: especially if these individuals are in high position or the position that the people count on them, their word spreads out like a rumor, for example they tell the employees of the company “next month such a person will be the top manager of our company” or “the company will increase the salaries by 10 percent or layoff 10 percent because of financial problems” but he doesn’t tell them this is his opinion or speculation and nobody ask the source of his statement    because he is in high position,that is why his opinion    spreads out as a news.

Answer (score 2):

**Opinionated**

The meaning given by OED is what we require for this case:

> Conceitedly assertive and dogmatic in one’s opinions: *an arrogant and opinionated man*

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinionated) gives a similar definition.

These definition are in slight contrast to many other dictionaries (for example [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=opinionated)), which say

> Holding stubbornly and often unreasonably to one's own opinions.

Other less polite terms we might employ are

- *Big-mouth*
- *Loud-mouth*

Answer (score 1):

The term I'd use is [**rumour-monger** (BrE) or **rumormonger** (AmE):](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rumour-monger)

> NOUN
>
> *derogator*y
>
> A person who spreads rumours.
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *A list of six names was compiled by the gossips and rumour-mongers of Belgravia, among them key figures from high society - aristocracy, government ministers and film stars.*
>
> *The rumour-mongers have portrayed me as a hard-bitten political adventuress devoid of all human feeling.*
>
> *What will these crazy rumour-mongers think of next?*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you're looking for is [dogmatic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogmatic). It means

> Expressing personal beliefs and opinions as if they are certainly correct and cannot be doubted or are facts.

Comment: This is an excellent word suggestion—and I would upvote it if it were self-contained—that is, if it included a dictionary definition to show why it is on point. But as it stands, your answer requires readers to look up the word _dogmatic_ to see why it is apt. Please consider adding a suitable definition to your answer (the one offered by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogmatic) actually uses the phrase "as if they were facts," so it would work extremely well, in my opinion).

Comment: I was going to upvote this answer, but then I noticed that the editing & addition of a reference have been carried out by a third-party & not by the original author of the answer.  In those circumstances, I don't consider that an upvote is appropriate for the author.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call him **"an unreliable source"**  Not an idiom, but it seems to translate what you are looking for.

"Forget what he said about us getting a bonus in December. He is a most unreliable source."

Answer (score 0):

Wishful thinker / doomsayer or alarmist (depending on the point of view)

Know-it-all

Cocky