# Is there a word for someone who treats their opinion as fact?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Thought that's what dogmatic meant but apparently it's not. Is there a word that describes this?

Comment: I think this might help: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218181/what-do-call-individuals-who-express-their-opinions-as-if-they-were-facts

Comment: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cocksure) defines: cocksure 1: feeling perfect assurance sometimes on inadequate grounds / 2: marked by overconfidence or presumptuousness : cocky

Comment: Answered at [Is there word for this, other than know-it-all?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203302/is-there-word-for-this-other-than-know-it-all). [This was closed as a duplicate, but the question title better matches the question here, and the answers certainly address this question.]